# Is there a page limitation with opening/downloading PDF's in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

It appears that there is a size limitation on PDF's being able to open them and I think the size corresponds to pages and not file size. I had a 50 page document that I was not able to open on the IPhone that was around 2 meg or so but I was able to open a 3 meg file that only had 8 pages and it opens. The PDF's I am opening are faxes being downloaded in a fax application.

Any thoughts? Is this a download issue or a UIWebView limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded and opened documents (in iBooks) that are 15mbs 400pages+. It takes awhile to download but I have not had any issues due to size. If you do not have iBooks installed, try installing and see if it will let you open in iBooks.